# Can't open a file through f.open()

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I wrote this code:

```
        f = open('mese.txt', 'a')
```

However, it seems that the file won't be created or, if I create it outside the program I'm writing, it won't be opened at all.
Also, the program runs, but when it comes to do these operation, the program itself crashes/ends with 0 error.
How can I get it working?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. What is `esistenzaMese`? What does `the program itself crashes` mean? are you getting an exception? How are you executing the program? Welcome to SO. Please read [mcve].

Comment: `open(fn, 'a')` is equivalent to `open(fn, 'w')` if `fn` already exists. As a rule, checking if a file exists before doing something based on that information leads to a race condition if someone else could create the file after you determine it doesn't exist, but before you can take an action that assumes it does not exist.

Comment: As mentioned by @wwii Please provide the necessary information need to assist you, for instance consider mentioning what `esistenzaMese` is.

Comment: How are you running the program? It sounds like the working directory where `mese.txt` is created is not the one you think it is.

Comment: @wwii I removed `esistenzaMese` as @chepner suggested. The program gives `Process finished with exit code 0`  and the largest part of it isn't executed. I tried with python from bash and 'run' in Pycharm IDE.

Comment: [Place the statement in a try/except block](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print/log the exception that is ocurring. Still not enough info in your question. Does the process that is executing the module have permission to write/create a file?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check anything. Just use

```
f = open('mese.txt', 'a')
```

If `mese.txt` doesn't already exist, the file is created and opened for writing, just like if you had written `open('mese.txt', 'w')`. Put another way, the only difference between `'w'` and `'a'` is irrelevant for an empty or not-yet-existing file.

Comment: Okay, I "cleaned up" the code. But still no operation is done on the file.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to open the file for appending. When you do, if the file exists, it is opened in append mode. If the file does not exist, it is created and opened in append mode.

```
# if exists, opens in append mode
# if does not exist, creates and opens in append mode
file_handle = open(file_path, 'a')
```

Although this is not neccesary, i recommend checkout out [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). It provides platform independant paths with methods for checking if they exists, or opening them.

```
from pathlib import Path
file_path = Path('mese.txt')
file_descriptor = file_path.open('a') # Opens (and creates) file for appending
exists = file_path.exists() # True if file exists
is_file = file_path.is_file() # True if the path leads to a file
```

Edit:

And of course, in each case, it is prefarable to use with statement.

```
with open(file_path, 'a') as file_descriptor:
    pass
```

This will close the file handle once you are done, even in case of an exception. `open` statement accepts both string path as well as `pathlib.Path` objects.

Comment: Can't you just use `with` and `open`? It's better because `with` will clean up the resources automatically when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are good, but if want just a straight forward solution, you can use `with`, like this:

```
with open('mese.txt', "a") as f:
    f.write(line)
```

`with` will clean up the resources afterward (no need to call `close()` manually) even if an exception occurs.

[Read about with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

Comment: I tried it, but my problem (I can't open or create the file) is still there.

Comment: @AlessioGiura - What is `esistenzaMese`? Clearly define what you need to do.

Comment: @AlessioGiura - Did you attempt to write a line to the file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. The problem was in other lines, while I was trying to campare strings and ints...

Comment: So you're actually able to write to a text file now?